# Updating existing excel file while it is open

Tags: c#, .net, linq, excel, vsto

I read a lot about how to communicate from C# to Excel and saw some good references.

The thing is I'm looking for an easy way to update existing excel file while it is still open, using 
the most advanced way (linq for example) and not OLEDB.

This should be few lines of code describing how can I read current cell, update his value and take into consideration the file might not be exist, but if it does exist and open, it will just update the file without giving the notification the file is already exist. If the file doesn't exist it will create a new one.

SO:
1. connect to an excel file, check if it exist, if not create one
2. read from cell
3. update cell
4. do this while the excel sheet can be still open wild.

I already visited the following places:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ef11a193-54f3-407b-9374-9f5770fd9fd7/writing-to-excel-using-c

[Updating an excel document programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923589/updating-an-excel-document-programmatically)

[Update specific cell of excel file using oledb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15894628/update-specific-cell-of-excel-file-using-oledb)

I used the following code:

```
   if (File.Exists(@"C:\\temp\\test.xls"))
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks workBooks = excelApp.Workbooks;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workBook = workBooks.Open(@"C:\\temp\\test.xls");
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet workSheet = workBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            int nColumns = workSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
            int nRows = workSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;

            for (int i = 2; i < nRows; i++)
            {
                workSheet.Columns["1","A"] = "test";
            }

            workBook.Save();
            workBook.Close();
        }
```

Comment: I don't get it. Where are you stuck? You've got your TO-DO list and it sounds like you can do it, so what is your question?  or did you want someone here to do your work.. Also just use the Object Model, dont bother using linq using the Open XML would be a much better choice.

Comment: No i don't know how to do it i would like to get a simple example of few lines of code describing my TO-DO list

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide/show us the code

Comment: I don't have a code, this is the code i need to do

Comment: Liad, what have you tried? The question sounds like you're asking us **to do your job** not `give us a hand with this problem`. There is a plethora of resources on Excel VSTO, I suggest you give it a go before asking questions here. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: @JeremyThompson i come across few examples but none of them helped me, i can put the code i've used but it didn't work, ok let me edit the question

Comment: Oh you've got half the solution already - apologies - this is what we need to help you.

Comment: Sure, but this lines are not working and causing excel to popup a window asking to recreate the excel file

Comment: To overcome that simply pass in a 3rd parameter of FALSE to the `workBooks.Open(@"C:\\temp\\test.xls", false, false);` method.

Comment: @JeremyThompson the think is is still want to replace the existing file and doesn't update it when the excel is still open i need to open and close it to see the changes

Answer (score 4):

So I use [VSTO Contrib](http://vstocontrib.codeplex.com) to help out with COM Interop and memory management and that's why you see `.WithComCleanup()`.

To open up a spreadsheet:

```
try
{
    using (var xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application().WithComCleanup())
    using (var wrkbooks = xlApp.Resource.Workbooks.WithComCleanup())
    using (var wrkbook = wrkbooks.Resource.Open(filePath, false, true).WithComCleanup())
    {
```

If the excel file is already open, then to get around the Read-Only follow this [tip](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/275976):

```
wrkbooks.Resource.Open(filePath, false, FALSE).WithComCleanup())
```

Here's how I iterate though the sheets (note that some Excel sheets are ChartSheets):

```
foreach (object possibleSheet in xlApp.Resource.Sheets)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet aSheet = possibleSheet as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;
    if (aSheet == null)
        continue;
```

Here is a quick way to get a reference to the sheet you're interested in:

```
activeSheet = wrkbook.Resource.Sheets[sheetToImport];
```

You read and write to cells just as you've identified:

```
for (int i = 2; i < nRows; i++)
{
  activeSheet.Columns["1","A"] = "test";
}
```

Here is how I close Excel:

```
MathematicaAPI.XlHelper.CloseExcel((Worksheet)activeSheet, (Workbook)wrkbook.Resource , (Workbooks)wrkbooks.Resource);

public static void CloseExcel(Worksheet activeSheet, Workbook wrkbook, Workbooks wrkbooks)
{
    //http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317109 -> excel just wont close for some reason
    if (activeSheet != null)
    {
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(activeSheet);
        activeSheet = null;
    }
    if (wrkbook != null)
    {
        wrkbook.Saved = true;
        wrkbook.Close(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAction.xlDoNotSaveChanges);
    }
    if (wrkbooks != null)
    {
        wrkbooks.Close();
    }
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}
```

Sometimes Excel just wont close and you have to kill it (after trying to close it properly of course) - I dont recommend this, but if you cant track down the un-disposed memory and all else fails then...

```
if (xlApp != null)
{
  ExcelDataSourceHelper.GetWindowThreadProcessId(new IntPtr(xlApp.Resource.Hwnd), ref excelProcessId);
}

if (excelProcessId > 0)
{
    XlHelper.KillProcess(excelProcessId);
}

public static void KillProcess(int excelProcessId)
{
    if (excelProcessId > 0)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process ExcelProc = null;
        try
        {
            ExcelProc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(excelProcessId);
            if (ExcelProc != null)
            {
                ExcelProc.Kill();
            }
        }
        catch
        { }
    }
}
```

Note: I reduce the chances of needing to kill Excel by using VSTO Contrib with `Using's`.

Comment: Jeremy thank you i'll try it soon, but can't i leave the excel open and just update it without open and close it? or not to say kill to process?

Comment: in addition the link you gave for VSTO Contrib doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

OK thank you all for trying to solve the issue
The solution was using Excel 2011/2013 Add-In which can communicate excel as a plugin

create an application-level add-in for Microsoft Office Excel. The features that you create in this kind of solution are available to the application itself, regardless of which workbooks are open.

You can visit [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668205.aspx)